# Error when attempting to access azure aks with kubectl

Tags: shell, terminal, kubectl, azure-aks

```
W0111 13:21:23.866650     172 azure.go:92] WARNING: the azure auth plugin is deprecated in v1.22+, unavailable in v1.26+; use https://github.com/Azure/kubelogin instead.

To learn more, consult https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#client-go-credential-plugins
```

This is the error I get in cmd, powershell, git-bash, azure shell & vscode terminal. Also I get the same issue if I go to the azure portal and use the web shell.

Yes if I use the terminal in Mirantis lens kubectl works as expected the only difference being is that I've added a http proxy in the Proxy settings for Lens.

I belive the issue is caused by the terminal not using the http proxy.

I've added a system environment variable through advanced system settings, which doesn't appear to be used in my terminal session.

How can I use the http proxy during sessions to use kubectl to access AKS and how can I check if the terminal is using the http proxy?

Installed kubelogin as above

Checked that the proxy was running using Get-Proxess px*

Checked that the environment variable was set with the correct value by doing ls $env: and listing all envvars

Answer (score 8):

Try this: https://github.com/Azure/kubelogin

1. brew install Azure/kubelogin/kubelogin
2. brew update
3. brew upgrade Azure/kubelogin/kubelogin
4. export KUBECONFIG={{/path/to/kubeconfig}} --> /home/{username}/.kube/config

(note: you can simply use ~/.kube/config in place of /home/{username}/.kube/config)

5. kubelogin convert-kubeconfig
6. kubectl get no

And again launch the desired commands

Comment: step 4 was unnecessary for me, worked like a charm with just the other steps.

Answer (score 2):

#### Warning or Error:

The azure auth provider is already removed as of today which was earlier deprecated. `kubelogin` is now the default way. So you might get:

`WARNING: the azure auth plugin is deprecated`

`error: The azure auth plugin has been removed`

#### Fix:

Below steps fixed the issue for me on windows:

1. Remove all the config folders inside user folder viz., `%USERPROFILE%` which will be `.kube`, `.azure-kubelogin`.
2. Then download and install the latest releases of [`kubectl`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-windows/#install-kubectl-binary-with-curl-on-windows) and [`kubelogin`](https://github.com/Azure/kubelogin/releases) (which is essentially just unzipping to a folder and adding that into user's `Path` environment variable.)
3. Perform:

```bash
az login
az account set --subscription <subscription id>
az aks get-credentials --resource-group <resource group name> --name <AKS cluster name>
kubelogin convert-kubeconfig -l azurecli
```

4. Now try: `kubectl get pods -A`

Answer (score 1):

1. Update the kubectl (use client version > 1.26)
2. run the below commands in a bash terminal

   az login

   az account set --subscription

   az aks get-credentials -n $AKS-cluster-name -g $resource-group-name

if you still find  the error below

> no Auth Provider found for name "azure" 
> error: The azure auth plugin has been removed.

Please use the kubectl/client-go credential plugin instead https://github.com/Azure/kubelogin

This is a client-go credential (exec) plugin implementing azure authentication. This plugin provides features that are not available in kubectl. It is supported on kubectl v1.11+

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the problem is with the client.

It seems you are using a client version > 1.26, which as the error suggests its removed.

The easiest thing you can do is to use an older version of the kubectl client.