# Error when trying to access azure aks with kubectl

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-cli

I went through this link - [Error when attempting to access azure aks with kubectl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75103364/error-when-attempting-to-access-azure-aks-with-kubectl) which talks about installing kubectl and kubelogin, but I am still not able to find a workaround.

This is basically what the problem is, after running these commands

```
az login
az account set --subscription
az aks get-credentials -n $AKS-cluster-name -g $resource-group-name
```

when I am trying to use kubectl,this is the error I get

```
error: The azure auth plugin has been removed
```

I have tried installing `kubectl` and `kubelogin` as mentioned in this forum earlier, but I still cannot run `kubectl get pods` or any other commands.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> kubectl get pods
error: The azure auth plugin has been removed.
Please use the https://github.com/Azure/kubelogin kubectl/client-go credential plugin instead.
See https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#client-go-credential-plugins for further details
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: Sometimes using `--admin` works as a workaround `az aks get-credentials -n $AKS-cluster-name -g $resource-group-name --admin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @*silent* for guiding in right direction.

As *@silent* mentioned, you have to use `az aks get-credentials -n $AKS-cluster-name -g $resource-group-name --admin` to download the Kubernetes configuration file with administrative privileges.

- The configuration file will include the credentials for the Kubernetes cluster administrator, which allows to perform administrative tasks on the cluster.
- Without `--admin` flag, the configuration file will only include the credentials for a regular user, which limits the tasks that you can perform on the cluster.

I have tried with `az aks get-credentials -n $AKS-cluster-name -g $resource-group-name --admin` and `az aks get-credentials -n $AKS-cluster-name -g $resource-group-name` in my environment. It worked in both cases as shown below:

**Command 1:**
[image]

**Command 2:**
[image]

[image]

**Reference:**

Refer to [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-ad-rbac?tabs=azure-cli#create-aks-cluster-resources-for-app-devs) for more info on '--admin' keyword as it returns the regular user creds of the AKS Cluster.